# Create clone of first two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create clone of first two div of `parent` Div.

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"> <div class="child1>Content1...</div> </div>
    <div class="child">Content2...</div>
    <div class="child">Content3...</div>
    <div class="child">Content4...</div>
    <div class="child">Content5...</div>
    <div class="child">Content6...</div>
</div>
```

**Expected output**

```
clone_object = '<div class="child"> <div class="child1>Content1...</div> </div>
                <div class="child">Content2...</div>'
```

I tried below code but it will clone only first div of parent div.

```
clone_object = $("#parent").find("div:first").clone();
```

My question is how to clone first two div of **parent** div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **[:lt](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)** selector.

> Select all elements at an index less than index within the matched set.

```
 $("#parent .child:lt(2)").clone();
```

or

```
 $("#parent>div:lt(2)").clone();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/meLz29qv/)**

Comment: It take first child with inner div of first div

Comment: Actually, I do not have child class as explained in example. I want first div using `parent` id

Comment: You can use immediate child selector  `$("#parent>div:lt(2)").clone();`